# I am getting Error : Cannot create object in nusoap

Tags: php, wsdl, nusoap

```
$url = "http://rgagroup.dyndns.org:8989/PactRevenUAPI/PACTRevenUAPIService.svc?wsdl";
    $xmlData="<SetDocument> <Key>pass123</Key> <CostCenterID>40007</CostCenterID> <Owner>Admin</Owner> <Header> <DocPrefix></DocPrefix> <DocNo></DocNo> <CustomerName> <Code>C4 - 47</Code> <Name>C4 - Al Dhait,Ras Al Khaima</Name> </CustomerName> </Header> <Body> <Row> <ProductCode> <Code>D05</Code> <Name>BALADE - Authentic Lebanese Labneh- Baraka 5kg</Name> </ProductCode> <Qty>1</Qty> <Units> <Code>pcs</Code><Name></Name> </Units> <UnitPrice>85</UnitPrice> </Row> </Body> </SetDocument>";

    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    $client = new nusoap_client($url, true);

    $error  = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    $Response_data = $client->call("SetDocument", $xmlData);


    print_r($Response_data);
```

This is my nusoup code and i am not getting response. can you help me how to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: use try catch instead

Comment: Be more specific. If no response, is there at least any php error? Do you have the error reporting enabled? var_dump $client and/or $Response_data...

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions?